# Angular 5 *ngIf параметры из запроса

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Имеется код

```
<li *ngIf="isRoot() || isSoftware()">
```

В самих методах isRoot и isSoftware используются данные, которые приходят ответом от бэка. Что-то на подобие следующего:

```
isRoot() {
    return this.service.Level == 'Root';
}
```

где service заполняется после получения ответа от сервера.
Как заставить шаблон в ngIf использовать данные этих функций только после того, как мы получили ответ от сервера?

Comment: Запрос на получение данных в service происходит в конструкторе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
<li *ngIf="service.Level && (isRoot() || isSoftware())">
```

Еще можно определить флаг...

```
public fetching: boolean = false;
public fetchLevel() {
    this.fetching = true;
    // Процессинг....
    this.fetching = false;
}
<div *ngIf="!fetching; else fetch">
    <li *ngIf="isRoot() || isSoftware()">
</div>
<ng-template #fetch><spinner></spinner></ng-template>
```

Comment: Ок, спасибо отредактирую.